# Como personalizar a numeração do Auto_Increment no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-incremento

Tenho uma coluna `Contrato` no meu banco de dados MySQL, ela está como `Auto_Increment,` numerando os contratos como *1*, *2*, *3*... Mas eu precisava, se possível, organizar esses números no formato real dos números de contrato.

Funciona assim, Ex.:

- Cliente Ana, Contrato: 22010-2015
- Cliente Tony, Contrato 22020-2015

Ou seja, aumentar de 10 em 10 apenas a classe `22000` e permanecer o ano `-2015`

É possível?

Mesmo se tiver que desativar o `Auto_Increment` e colocar um código php na área do cadastramento?

Comment: Isso é uma pratica terrível, você está em um banco relacional, você pode simplesmente criar um campo para armazenar essa data e utiliza-la como critério nas querys

Comment: Mas para seguir o modelo relacional eu já possuo o campo ID, que segue o padrão do banco de dados, no caso eu queria uma facilidade para consultar os contratos, assim eu deixaria de ter um outro banco de dados, que atualmente é o Microsoft Excel e deixaria tudo online.

Comment: você pode construir uma trigger no insert, da uma olhada
[trigger](http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você terá que fazer três coisas:

1. Criar uma tabela para armazenar o número do último contrato.
2. Criar um gatilho para garantir que a cada inserção seja usado o número sequencial
3. Criar uma função que calcule o próximo número de contrato baseado nas regras definidas e no número encontrado na tabela citada anteriormente.

Sem dúvida não poderá usar o [`AUTO INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) do MySQL.

Algo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE sequencia_contrato (
    sequencial INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ano INT
);
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER numero_contrato BEFORE INSERT ON contrato
FOR each ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.contrato = PegaNumeroContrato();
END
```

Função:

Basicamente terá que o valor da tabela acima, somar 10, se eu entendi que é isto que você quer. E pegar o ano corrente. Se o ano corrente for maior que o ano registrado na tabela de controle da sequência, o ano lá deverá ser atualizado para o ano corrente e a sequência deverá ser *resetada*. Talvez nem seja exatamente isto que você deseja.

```
CREATE FUNCTION PegaNumeroContrato() RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
    //precisa melhorar ainda, falta tratar o ano, por exemplo
    DECLARE ultimo_valor INT;
    SET ultimo_valor = (SELECT sequencial FROM sequencia_contrato);
    SET ultimo_valor = ultimo_valor + 1;
    UPDATE sequencia_contrato SET sequencial = ultimo_valor;
    SET @resultado = (SELECT concat(lpad(ultimo_valor, 5, '0'), '-', CAST((SELECT ano FROM sequencia_contrato) AS CHAR(4))));
    RETURN @resultado;
END
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Trigger2.sql).

Comment: Sou apenas um "fuçador" em php, não conheço esse tipo de código, caso seja complexo, eu posso colocar o ano como parte do código anterior, ex.: 201522010, e posso preencher ele manualmente, já que demora para mudar, o importante pra mim é adicionar 10 a cada número inserido, sendo que já possuo cadastro partindo de 22000

Comment: O processo será todo feito no MySQL, não é seguro fazer pelo PHP. Realmente pode acertar manual mas não é o ideal.

Comment: Eu estou migrando do SQL Server pro MySQL e aproveitando a pergunta, como eu posso incrementar iniciando do 0? No SQL Server é assim: `ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(0,1)`, mas como faço isso no MySQL?

Comment: Perguntas devem ser feitas como perguntas, esta área é apenas para comentar sobre a resposta dada, não para continuar o assunto.

Comment: Tome cuidado pois face ao volume de inclusões simultâneas podem ocorrer duplicidades de chave, não conheço como funciona o "lock" de tabela no Mysql para opinar , como disse o Isvaldo uma má prática , tipo da coisa que só se faz se houver exigência legal.