# Como adicionar uma coluna no banco de dados em que seu valor seja igual ao ano atual + o campo id da tabela?

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada "usuarios" no banco de dados. 
Veja abaixo a estrutura da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de inserir um campo chamado "matricula" varchar (50), ali depois do campo "id". Porém eu gostaria que esse campo "matricula" fosse **auto_increment** e **unique**. (até ai tudo bem, eu sei fazer).

O problema é que eu gostaria que esse campo "matricula" sempre recebesse o valor (automaticamente) do: **ano atual** **+** o campo "**id**".

Por exemplo, se ao inserir um novo usuário o id dele fosse 741, então o seu campo "matricula" automaticamente receberia o valor de "2020741".

**OBS:** Lembrando que isso seria feito em uma tabela já existente e com dados.

**OBS2:** Sei que daria pra fazer isso na hora de inserir os dados com a linguagem de programação (php no meu caso), porém eu gostaria de fazer isso diretamente com o **MySQL**.

Desde já, agradeço a atenção. Obrigado !

Comment: Para os dados já existentes, você vai precisa fazer algum update, para os novos dados, já pensou em trabalhar com alguma trigger?

Comment: É, uma trigger seria até uma boa opção. Mas isso não daria para ser definido na criação do campo ?

Comment: Existe o valor default para os campos, mas como vai ser algo mais dinâmico, que vai exigir inclusive um tratamento da data pra pegar o ano, não sei se é possível, nunca tentei, mas vale a pena pesquisar, se aceitar uma função por exemplo, você poderia criar essa função no MySql e associar ao default do campo.

Comment: Opa, parece que é possível sim utilizar uma expressão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52492/como-personalizar-a-numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-auto-increment-no-mysql

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, Daniel e Rodrigo. Retorno para vocês se me serviu. Obrigado !

Comment: Será que talvez não dê para colocar o default como o ano atual + o campo id ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não diria que essa é uma boa abordagem, mas deve resolver o seu problema.. esse seria o insert do campo da matricula.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER `usuarios_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `usuarios` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.matricula IS NULL THEN
    SET new.matricula = (SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), (SELECT `auto_increment` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE table_name = 'usuario' ORDER BY `auto_increment` desc LIMIT 1)) AS id)
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: Como eu mencionei na pergunta, amigão, nesse caso eu teria que fazer essa query na linguagem de programação, e a intenção é fazer isso diretamente no mysql.

Comment: Acho que é no caminho de um alter table tabela add column ... bla bla bla ...

Comment: Se eu entendi agora, acredito que essa trigger poderá resolver seu problema.. durante o insert ele irá gerar a matricula.

Comment: João, vou tentar ver se consigo fazer diretamente no campo. Se não conseguir, parto para sua trigger. Te dou um retorno. Obrigado !